# How to print an element in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html

So there are 9 cells(id from cell0-cell8) whose content that I need to keep track of and store in a multidimensional array:

```js
var winningcombos = [
  [
    document.getElementById("cell" + 0).innerHTML, 
    document.getElementById("cell" + 1).innerHTML,
    document.getElementById("cell" + 2).innerHTML
  ],
  [
    document.getElementById("cell" + 3).innerHTML, 
    document.getElementById("cell" + 4).innerHTML,
    document.getElementById("cell" + 5).innerHTML
  ],
  [
    document.getElementById("cell" + 6).innerHTML, 
    document.getElementById("cell" + 7).innerHTML,
    document.getElementById("cell" + 8).innerHTML
  ],
];
```

However when I am trying to print the element inside the array, for example the first cell, it doesn't seem to work:

```
document.write(winningcombos[0][0])
```

Can't find the problem using console.log.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No. It just doesn't print anything

Comment: little typo `,` at the end

Comment: @Blazemonger How is it one-dimensional? If so how do I make it multidimensional?  I want to reach the element by winningcombos[0][0]

Comment: @phalanx Comma is allowed at the end of array or object literals.

Comment: can you show the HTML that includes `id='cellnum'`?

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/tvuon9k3/3/ Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write()` after the DOM has been loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Just note that `"cell" + 6` is the same as `"cell6"`. I'm not sure why you're using concatenation there...

Comment: try doing it within: window.onload = function () {}

Comment: @Omiinahellcat If that were the issue he would be getting an error saying that it's trying to get the property `innerHTML` of `null`.